# Navigating to Parent fragment from Child After Replace

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin

im trying to navigate to parent fragment after completing the action in the child fragment. im able to successfully navigate from parent to child but having trouble when going backwards. the code im using currently is

From Parent to Child

```
 public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            switch (item.ItemId)
            {
                case Resource.Id.action_new:
                    FragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
                                   .Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, EditAccountFragment.NewInstance())
                                   .AddToBackStack("AccountFragment")
                                   .Commit();                   
                    break;
            }
            return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

From Child to Parent

```
public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            switch (item.ItemId)
            {
                case Resource.Id.action_save:
                    SaveAccount();
                    GotoAccounts();
                    Toast.MakeText(Activity, "Save Account", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    break;
                case Resource.Id.action_cancel:
                    GotoAccounts();
                    Toast.MakeText(Activity, "Save Account Cancelled", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    break;
            }
            return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        private void GotoAccounts()
        {

            AccountsFragment accountsFragment = new AccountsFragment();
            FragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
                                   .Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, accountsFragment)
                                   .Commit();
        }

        private void SaveAccount()
        {
            Account.AccountName = Title.Text;
            Account.Note = Note.Text;
            _accountDM.SaveAccount(Account);
        }
```

Can anyone please help me in getting this work to navigate from Child to Parent? 
i want the user to redirect to listing page once he save the account in child fragment automatically.

Thanks for all or Any help.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, because you added the child fragment to the backstack, navigate back it only matter to call `onBackPressed()` on the `MainActivity`, the systems should handle the rest

```
            case Resource.Id.action_save:
                SaveAccount();
                getActivity().onBackPressed();
                Toast.MakeText(Activity, "Save Account", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                break;
```

Give it a try and see if that solves your problem!

Comment: I just saw the logcat you posted. I believe the problem is in your `Toast`. Can you remove that line and see if it runs this time?

Comment: Sorry it didnt work. it thrown an exception on Toast method. i removed the toast and it didnt work still.

Comment: Does it crash? or just doesn't do anything?

Comment: What do you mean no logs? If it crashed there must be an output in your log. Please post it

Comment: i changed the code to private void GotoAccounts()
        {
            try
            {
                Activity.OnBackPressed();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Debug("ExpenseTracker", e.ToString());
            }
        } but still it didnt create any logs for the particular run in LogCat.

Comment: i even tried just e.Message, just to see if it logs any message, but it didnt log any. i tried to step through the application and looks like it didnt even threw any exception. the app just crashing